# Angular datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I use bootstrap datepicker and have following issue:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-click="viewModel.toggleDatepicker()" ng-model="viewModel.selectedDate" min-date="viewModel.datepicker.minDate" max-date="viewModel.datepicker.maxDate" datepicker-options="viewModel.datepicker.options"show-button-bar="false" />
```

and in Controller:

```
var today = this.selectedDate;
var nextWeek = this.selectedDate;
nextWeek.setDate(nextWeek.getDate() + this.DaysSlots);
```

after those lines gets executed both today and nextWeek points to the same date. Why is that?

Thanks for response

Comment: What does this.DaysSlots get for you?

Comment: this.DaysSlots is const value of type number

Comment: this.selectedDate, i hope you get it as a Date Object... and you don't need to wrap it again with new Date(obj) right?

Comment: actually I assign this.selectedDate = new Date() in constructor to make it point to current Date, if it is what you ask about?

Comment: can you console out (today and nextWeek) before setting nextWeek.setDate() to ensure the values are different.... and my guess is nextWeek and today are pointing to same reference which might be causing you this issue.

Comment: right, reference was the issue. I didnt know that new variable assigned to original object still points to that object. Thanks Thalaivar

Answer (score 1):

To make your overall experince with angular dates better, you should look into moment .js

http://momentjs.com/

It allows you to create, format, add and subtract dates easily and with minimal issues. Using the default date.setDate function can cause lots of issues